# What is the difference between `for` and `while` loops in my Script

Tags: javascript

I have a JavaScript function that collects a number of `input` tags into an array and then decides if one of them has been selected:

```
function validateAnswerSelected () {
    var formValid = false;
    var groupedInput = document.getElementsByName("choice");
    var i;

    // while (!formValid && i < questions[questionNumber].choices.length) {
    //  if (groupedInput[i].checked) {
    //      formValid = true;
    //  }
    //  i++;
    // }

    // for (i = 0; questions[questionNumber].choices.length; i++) {
    //  if (groupedInput[i].checked) {
    //      formValid = true;
    //  }
    // }

    if (!formValid) {
        alert("select an answer");
    }
}
```

When I uncomment the `while` loop the function works correctly. However when I uncomment the `for` loop `groupedInput` becomes undefined.

What is the difference here?

Edit: when I uncomment the `while` then I do initialise the `i` variable. The error I made in the question is just a typo.

Comment: In case of while you don't initialize `i = 0`

Comment: BTW, if you used while loop here not to look over all elements, you can achieve same effect using break statement in a for loop.

Comment: is questions global ?

Comment: @DontVoteMeDown `groupedInput[undefined]` isn't working, the `while` loop body never executes; `undefined < int` evaluates to false.

Comment: for (i = 0; questions[questionNumber].choices.length; i++) There is no Condition to check!!!

Comment: @Sam1604 yep. That is the error. I made a typo.

Comment: @DontVoteMeDown Well, with the code they've posted that statement is incorrect. If `i` is `undefined` then it doesn't work correctly, it just possibly looks that way because the entire `while` loop is skipped over. If the `while` loop does, in fact, work correctly then `i` is not `undefined`. Based on comments by the OP on the single answer, they *are* defining `i`.

Comment: @AnthonyGrist, Yes I am when I use the `while` loop. But not for the `for` loop.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Typo:

```
for (i = 0; questions[questionNumber].choices.length; i++) {
```

Should be:

```
for (i = 0; i < questions[questionNumber].choices.length; i++) {
//           ^ You forgot the `i <`
```

Comment: `while` is also a problem He son't internalize `i`

Comment: Oh boy, now I feel really stupid. Thanks

Comment: I should have added that when I uncomment the while loop then I do initialize it.

Answer (score 0):

You didn't assign a value for "i" before using a while loop.

> Blockquote var i;      *//default is undefined*

But, in for loop you have assigned inside of that.

> Blockquote for (i = 0; questions[questionNumber].choices.length; i++) {

That's why it returns undefined.

Sollution:

var i = 0;

Now it works fine. :)